# Wifi connects but can't ping ubuntu 14.04.2 with Intel 7260

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, intel-wireless

After moving to a new location I haven't been been able to get the wifi working properly. My laptop finds the network ok and can connect to it, but no data is able to pass through. Momentarily it does work, but only for a second or two at a time. After purging and reinstalling resolvconf I got up to 10 minutes of working connection, but now it is down again.

Pinging 8.8.8.8 results:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 16100ms

Pinging 192.168.0.1 results:

PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.102 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4023ms
pipe 3
```

My android device and other devices work properly with the network, and my ubuntu has not been suffering with problems with other networks.

My situation is unfortunately one where I cannot modify the network itself, but since other devices are working great, I suspect the problem is not there.

I'm not really familiar with Ubuntu networking, so there could be even something simple I'm missing here, even though I'v tried looking at the discussion and other questions around here. Thank you all for the help.

Here is the report from the wifi script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 Aug 2015 20:14 EEST +0300

Booted last: 04 Aug 2015 19:47 EEST +0300

Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:572a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                217725  0 
mac80211              652777  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               179412  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              498458  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    19193  0 
ideapad_laptop         18278  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.43.63  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2888 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:968332 (968.3 KB)  TX bytes:426996 (426.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"AndroidAP"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:64   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       855     1  0 19:47 ?        00:00:01 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

** (process:3553): WARNING **: error: cannot retrieve connection: uid 1000 has no permission to perform this operation

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [AndroidAP] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Blink1861D1:     Infra, <MAC 'Blink1861D1' [AC2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52 WEP
    bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio: Infra, <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74 WPA2
    *AndroidAP:      Infra, <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 76 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.43.63
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.43.1

    DNS:             192.168.43.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio]] (600 root)
[connection] id=bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/vodafone3B54]] (600 root)
[connection] id=vodafone3B54 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=vodafone3B54 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto


[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Helsinki (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AndroidAP"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000043710d9
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Blink1861D1' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Blink1861D1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000396e5c4d1
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000003971b1b6f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 32ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     C3CE81DD94553577D83E97E
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     315DCE1E2614AE1F38132D3
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
srcversion:     93D664267873827B22C4309
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D48679749A6B8B822E391CA
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b2 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[  732.387498] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  733.152653] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]>
[  733.155625] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[  733.157833] wlan0: authenticated
[  733.160589] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[  733.167774] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]> (capab=0x31 status=0 aid=2)
[  733.170123] wlan0: associated
[ 1535.375017] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'bob-net-no-3-03-227742-colocatio' [AC3]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1536.145109] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]>
[ 1536.147831] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1536.150625] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1536.154594] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1536.168542] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'AndroidAP' [AC1]> (capab=0x8431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1536.168930] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable some options of the driver.

Run in terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Editor will open. Paste there this text

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0 swcrypto=1
```

save the file and reboot.

I disabled all options in the last line that may make trouble. You can remove some of them and test if that is needed. But it should work this way.

**Update:** for kernel 4.2 these options are not needed. Intel 7260 works well "out of the box".

You can update your kernel to 4.2 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

For some country codes there may also be a trouble with regional restrictions. You can use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/727594/167850) if that affects you.

I also found that `uapsd` works quite well too. It is disabled by default, but can be enabled by

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "uapsd_disable=N"
```

But there is a possibility that it does not work well with all access points. `uapsd` allows to save some power in certain cases.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there seems to be no difference. And sorry for the messy first post, thanks for editing.

Comment: I added other options that may cause these problems. Try the new command and reboot.

Comment: Do not run away please. I will update the answer.

Comment: @SamuliL I added directions how to return default config and add there the new line. Please do it. And also you can accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left.

Comment: @Pilot6: I too had similar problems. I tried too many solutions over the internet which looked similar to yours (a bit different in parameters), but none seemed to work. But thanks to your solution, it worked to some extent. The problem doesn't seem to have solved completely but now it is not that frequent and is not that worse either. 

Can you explain me what exactly this is doing, so that I can try to tweak some bit here and there and try to fix it completely.

Thanks anyways, I am at least able to work now. Thanks a tonne :)

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/a/660158/167850    http://askubuntu.com/q/727593/167850  @Anuj

Comment: I have this adapter now and it works perfectly without these options.

Comment: So what I understand is:
1. The problem is mainly due to relatively weak wifi signal. If I am seated next to the router, I ill not have this issue.
2. There are these 4 parameters, which can affect the working of my adapter. Some combination of these four can improve the wifi strength to some extent.
3. Intel 7260 wireless adapter has some issues due to which they keep scanning for networks if they wifi signal is weak. And that is when "it is disconnected for a short time from AP or transmission stops because of this conflict."
Is my understanding clear?

Comment: These parameters will not improve the signal strength. This is a workaround of some driver/firmware bugs. It is fixed now. But if you connect at 5 GHz and your country code regdomain is not supported, you can have some issues.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question. Probably you need to upgrade the kernel. This solution was written long ago for kernel 3.16.

Comment: Okay. I will ask a new question. But is there a way we can chat? I have too many questions and I am getting confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35344/discussion-between-anuj-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0):

I had taken some of the steps mentioned here previously. As i was reading through i noticed the mention of 5GHz frequency. I had switched my Access Point [Android Hotspot on HTC One M8 running CyanogenMod 6.0.0] to the 5GHz Band in the hotspot settings and the problem disappeared.  WikiPedia clearly shows that 2.4 GHz frequency should only be used with knowledge that a WiFi network will  not interfere with any other 802.11 or non-802.11 (such as Bluetooth) system using the same frequencies.