# Problem with Intel 7260 wireless adapter on 5 GHz on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I installed a new Intel 7260 dual band adapter into an ASUS laptop.

The adapter works OK on 2.4 GHz, but on 5 GHz it disconnects frequently for a short time. This makes impossible to watch videos or play games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found a solution.

These new Intel adapters support high mobility and scan for networks frequently.

Ubuntu 14.04 has an outdated `wireless-regdb` package version `2013.02.13-1ubuntu1`. For many countries it does not allow to use 5GHz channels.

When the adapter tries to scan, it is disconnected for a short time from AP or transmission stops because of this conflict.

This can be checked by `iw reg get` command. The command will output the allowed frequencies and the country code.

If you do not see the frequencies allowed in your country, you can update the `wireless-regdb` package to the latest one built for Ubuntu 16.04.

Run this in terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wireless-regdb/wireless-regdb_2015.07.20-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i wireless-regdb*.deb
```

If your country code has been properly updated in this package, the problem should be solved after a reboot.

I reported this issue to [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireless-regdb/+bug/1539448).

You can vote that this issue affects you, if this is the case.

Now my 7260 adapter works very well.

Comment: Great find @Pilot6!